# stack panel not showing all button's images but i need those to not be clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

i have four stackpanels in a grid and i keep on adding and removing buttons using C#. i need to be able only to click the top one (the lowest one) but i need to be able to see all of the images of the buttons above it.
this is how i did it but i can't see the images:

```
    public bool isTop { get; private set; }

    public void NotTop()
    {
        isTop = false;
        this.Item_Button.IsEnabled = false;

    }

    public void IsNowTop()
    {
        isTop = true;
        this.Item_Button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

is there any way that i can make them not clickable and still see the Image in the button's background?

Comment: You could set a flag in the button's click event that checks to see if a boolean value is true. Basically, the click event would include `if (buttonClickable) { // execute code }` This would not change the display of the button, but only run code if `buttonClickable == true`

Comment: `i have four stackpanels in a grid and i keep on adding and removing buttons using C#` - delete all that and use  proper XAML  and DataBinding.